# jQuery .combobox() breaks SPCascadeDropdowns relationship

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery, spcascadedropdowns

I've implemented SPCascadeDropdowns functionality on SharePoint Online into my new item form. That's ok and it works.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
      relationshipList: "CostCenter",
      relationshipListParentColumn: "Company",
      relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
      parentColumn: "Company",
      childColumn: "CostCenter"
  });
});
```

[image: Working SPCascadeDropdowns functionality]

However because plenty of Companies and Cost Centers I want to implement autocomplete functionality like [jQuery autocomplete combobox](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) is.

The autocomplete works fine but problem is when I do that **it will break relationship** between those two input fields. So I can pick up values from Company but not from CostCenter because it's always empty.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
      relationshipList: "CostCenter",
      relationshipListParentColumn: "Company",
      relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
      parentColumn: "Company",
      childColumn: "CostCenter"
  });
 });

 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("select[title='Company']").combobox();
     $("select[title='CostCenter']").combobox();
 });
```

[image: Not working with jQuery autocomplete implementation]

Thank you for your helpful hints. It will be probably connected  with my poor  javascript knowledge.

**Update**: 
When I apply this jQuery autocomplete only on second input it works fine.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
      relationshipList: "CostCenter",
      relationshipListParentColumn: "Company",
      relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
      parentColumn: "Company",
      childColumn: "CostCenter"
  });
 });

 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("select[title='CostCenter']").combobox();
 });
```

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Per my testing, this issue is caused by the change event in .SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns will not be triggered because the selected option value is not changed.
 [image]

To resolve this, we need to overwrite the autocomplete source code and cascading function.

Custom cascading function -- refer to:

http://www.markrackley.net/2014/05/20/cascading-drop-down-lists-in-sharepoint-office-365-using-rest/

Also call the cascading function in `this._on` method within autocomplete function. After that, when the parent value is changed, the child values will be changed.

Demo:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"/>

<style>
.custom-combobox {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}
.custom-combobox-toggle {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin-left: -1px;
padding: 0;
}
.custom-combobox-input {
margin: 0;
padding: 5px 10px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  HillbillyCascade({
    parentFormField: "Company", //Display name on form of field from parent list
    childList: "CostCenter", //List name of child list
    childLookupField: "Title", //Internal field name in Child List used in lookup
    childFormField: "CostCenter", //Display name on form of the child field
    parentFieldInChildList: "Company" //Internal field name in Child List of the parent field
  });

  (function( $ ) {
$.widget( "custom.combobox", {
_create: function() {
this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
.addClass( "custom-combobox" )
.insertAfter( this.element );

this.element.hide();
this._createAutocomplete();
this._createShowAllButton();
},

_createAutocomplete: function() {
var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
this.input = $( "<input>" )
.appendTo( this.wrapper )
.val( value )
.attr( "title", "" )
.addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
.autocomplete({
delay: 0,
minLength: 0,
source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
})
.tooltip({
tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
});

this._on( this.input, {
autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
ui.item.option.selected = true;
this._trigger( "select", event, {
item: ui.item.option
});
// trigger cascading here when result is changed
DoHillbillyCascade(ui.item.option.value,{
    parentFormField: "Company", //Display name on form of field from parent list
    childList: "CostCenter", //List name of child list
    childLookupField: "Title", //Internal field name in Child List used in lookup
    childFormField: "CostCenter", //Display name on form of the child field
    parentFieldInChildList: "Company" //Internal field name in Child List of the parent field
  }); 
},

autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
});
},

_createShowAllButton: function() {
var input = this.input,
wasOpen = false;

$( "<a>" )
.attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
.attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
.tooltip()
.appendTo( this.wrapper )
.button({
icons: {
primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
},
text: false
})
.removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
.addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
.mousedown(function() {
wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
})
.click(function() {
input.focus();

// Close if already visible
if ( wasOpen ) {
return;
}

// Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
});
},

_source: function( request, response ) {
var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
var text = $( this ).text();
if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
return {
label: text,
value: text,
option: this
};
}) );
},

_removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {

// Selected an item, nothing to do
if ( ui.item ) {
return;
}

// Search for a match (case-insensitive)
var value = this.input.val(),
valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
valid = false;
this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
this.selected = valid = true;
return false;
}
});

// Found a match, nothing to do
if ( valid ) {
return;
}

// Remove invalid value
this.input
.val( "" )
.attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
.tooltip( "open" );
this.element.val( "" );
this._delay(function() {
this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
}, 2500 );
this.input.autocomplete( "instance" ).term = "";
},

_destroy: function() {
this.wrapper.remove();
this.element.show();
}
});
})( jQuery );
    $("select[title='Company']").combobox();
    $("select[title='CostCenter']").combobox();

//  $("select[title='Company']").parent().find("input").change(function(){alert("work");});
function HillbillyCascade(params)
    {

        var parent = $("select[Title='"+params.parentFormField+"'], select[Title='"+
            params.parentFormField+" Required Field']");

        var currentParent = $(parent).val();       
            DoHillbillyCascade(currentParent,params);
    }


    function DoHillbillyCascade(parentID,params)
    {

        var child = $("select[Title='"+params.childFormField+"'], select[Title='"+
            params.childFormField+" Required Field']," +
           "select[Title='"+params.childFormField+" possible values']");

        $(child).empty();

        var options = "";

        var call = $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('"+params.childList+
                "')/items?$select=Id,"+params.childLookupField+","+params.parentFieldInChildList+
                "/Id&$expand="+params.parentFieldInChildList+"/Id&$filter="+params.parentFieldInChildList+
                "/Id eq "+ parentID,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
            }

        });
        call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){

            for (index in data.d.results)
            {
                options += "<option value='"+ data.d.results[index].Id +"'>"+
                    data.d.results[index][params.childLookupField]+"</option>";
            }
            $(child).append(options);

        });
        call.fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
            alert("Error retrieving information from list: " + params.childList + jqXHR.responseText);
            $(child).append(options);
        });

    }

    });

</script>
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much for your answer. However, I have two problem with this:

1. I'm getting this error:

[image]

2. The cascade selection now works "fine", but only once. When I select parent Company then it correctly offer CostCenters but then when I **click againg** on that arrow **it will offer me something different**. Plus when I try to save the item the **CostCenter column is empty**

[image] 
[image]

I'm using two tables:

*Companies* with column CompanyName(Title), ComapnyCode
*CostCenter* with columns CostCenter(Tilte), CostCenterCode, Company(lookup from the Companies)

That's correct right?